# Is there any way to not allow special characters in a textform field in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want a text form field which will accept only alphabets not digits and special characters. If the user clicks on special character also that character on click in key board type should not work.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a inputFormatter will work.

- 'a-z' - small alphabets
- 'A-Z' - Capital alphabets
- ' ' - Will allow space between

To allow space between

```
    inputFormatter: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z ]")),
     ],
```

No space between

```
    inputFormatter: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]")),
     ],
```

Digits only

```
    inputFormatter: [
           FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add inputFormatters property to your TextField widget like this:

```
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]")),
],
```